# H2 Java Insert ignore - allow exception

Tags: java, exception, h2

I am working on a java plugin interfacing with an H2 database. What I really want is an "Insert Ignore" statement; however, I'm aware that H2 doesn't support this. I am also aware of Merge, but this is really not what I want, if the record exists I don't want to change it.

What I am considering is to just run the insert and let the duplicate key exception happen. However, I don't want this to fill my log file. The DB call happens in an imported class that I can't change. So my questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable thing to do? I'm not one for letting errors happen, but this seems like the best way in this case (it should not happen all that much).
2. How can I keep this exception from hitting my log file? If there isn't a way to block exceptions down the stack, can I redirect the output of the stack trace that is output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is to use:

```
insert into test 
select 1, 'Hello' from dual 
where not exists(select * from test where id = 1)
```

This should work for all databases (except for the dual part; you may need to create your own dummy table with one row).

To disable logging exceptions, append `;trace_level_file=0` to the database URL:

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;trace_level_file=0
```

or run the SQL statement:

```
set trace_level_file 0
```

Comment: Nice workaround- already did something similar with 2 separate queries while waiting. I would still like to know about the Java exceptions though.

Comment: I'm not going to bother testing this, but I'm not sure it will work (gave you the points anyway). The exception I'm referring to is logged in the app, not from h2 directly.

Comment: I would post my code/log, but it's not my code to post. Thanks.

Comment: "except for the dual part; you may need to create your own dummy table with one row".

That sounds very hacky.